# Carbon methods returning 0

Tags: laravel

I have this method in model class ,basically i want to get the duration beetwen 2 dates and return in in hours and seconds but is keep returning 0

```
public function getDuration(){
        
        $start = Carbon::parse($this->created_at);
        $end = Carbon::parse(now());

        $hours = $end->diffInHours($start);

        $seconds = $end->diffInSeconds($end);

        return $hours . ':' . $seconds;
    }
```

In blade

```
<td>{{$drug->getDuration()}}</td>
```

Comment: Change `$end = Carbon::parse(now());` to `$end = now();`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ $hours is working but not $seconds .

Comment: because you are using the same variable `$end->diffInSeconds($end);` should be `$seconds = $end->diffInSeconds($start);`

Comment: Also, just for you to know, `now()` is an alias of `Carbon::now()`, so you can also use that but not `Carbon::parse(now())`. You can also use `Carbon::today()` if you want, but it will have hours, minutes and seconds = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think  you can use format instead of finding difference separately.

```
 public function getDuration(){

        $start = $this->created_at;
        $end = now();
        return $end->diff($start)->format('%H:%S');
    }
```